# How to automate fuzzing in ZAP?

Tags: zap, fuzzing, security-testing

We have a requirement as below to automate in ZAP

1. Go through POST request in ZAP tool
2. Identify values which got posted in Request tab
3. Highlight the value passed(for example: to textarea field) and right click > goto Fuzzer
4. Choose required injections like SQL Injection or RDF Injection etc.,
5. Add payload
6. Start fuzzer

Expected result would be to generate a comparison report of request before and after fuzzing is done.

Can this be automated in ZAP?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Fuzzer doesn't have a web API. Largely due to the fact that we're lacking user input on how such functionality should work and what their expectations for it might be.

Here's the existing issue you should provide your feedback on: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/1689

There is an unfinished PR adding an initial implementation, you could pull the PR branch and build the add-on for testing purposes and to potentially encourage the submitting user to complete it: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/pull/2222